# Trying to create a git repo that does an automatic checkout everytime someone updates origin

Tags: git

Basically, I have a server with a git repo 'origin'. I'm trying to have another repo auto-pull from origin every time someone pushes code to it. I've been using the hooks in origin, specifically post-receive. So far, my post receive looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_DIR=/home/<user>/<test_repo>
git pull origin master
```

But when I push to origin from another computer, I get the error:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/<user>/<test_repo>'
```

However, test_repo most definitely is a git repo. I can cd into it and run 'git pull origin master' and it works fine.

Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? If not, what am I doing wrong with this approach? Thanks in advance.

Edit, to clarify: The repo is a website in progress, and I'd like to have a version of it available at all times that is fully up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a similar hook, but GIT_DIR must point to the .git subdirectory.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/<user>/<test_repo>
GIT_DIR=.git git pull origin master
```

Comment: Just to note, changing into the repository doesn't require that you set `GIT_DIR`--it gets this automatically be parsing parent directories.

Comment: Have you checked that? I have tested without setting GIT_DIR and it didn't work from post-receive (git 1.7.x afair), probably because GIT_DIR is set there to the repo being pushed to.

Answer (score 3):

When you set an environment variable, its only available within that shell--so when you launch another program, such as git, the local variables won't get passed along.  Lets say we have `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "GIT_DIR=$GIT_DIR"
```

Now lets look at the following examples

```
$ GIT_DIR=LOOK_MY_GIT_DIR_IS_SET
$ ./test.sh
GIT_DIR=
```

This is because the environment variable didn't get *exported* to the launched program.

```
$ export GIT_DIR=LOOK_MY_GIT_DIR_IS_SET
$ ./test.sh
GIT_DIR=LOOK_MY_GIT_DIR_IS_SET
```

In ScottZ's example, setting the environment variable when you launch the program causes it to be exported ONLY for that command.

```
$ GIT_DIR=LOOK_MY_GIT_DIR_IS_SET ./test.sh
GIT_DIR=LOOK_MY_GIT_DIR_IS_SET
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point, so not only do you need to make sure you are using the .git extension if the repo is non-bare you also need to export the variable in your script.

Comment: Right; if you wanted, you could always `cd` into the git repository before running your pull.  I.e., `cd /home/<user>/<test_repo> && git pull origin master`.  This might be a little clearer and easier.

Comment: You are correct, but not solving the OP question.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted silk's question because it was more direct, but your explanations were really useful.

Comment: Glad it helped, Dane. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are setting GIT_DIR properly?

I assume you are pulling from a non-bare repo in that case your GIT_DIR should be

```
GIT_DIR=/home/user/test_repo/.git
```

To test this run the following on the command line:

```
GIT_DIR=/home/user/test_repo/.git git status
```